# Problem on boot: Starting Version 219

Tags: 15.04, lightdm, acer, versions

After installing Ubuntu 15.04 when I start the system appears the message, which carries with it takes longer to boot. If anyone can help would be grateful.

complement:

Already tested the command:

```
sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service -f
```

and got the following result:

```
Synchronizing state for lightdm.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d lightdm defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d lightdm enable
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
.wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

And the problem still persists. If you can help me would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know why it's happened , also I check my `fstab` by `blkid`
to have right UUID and it was true so I use this script for upgrade my kernel to 4.0.1 stable:

for 32 bit :

```
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.1-wily/linux-headers-4.0.1-040001_4.0.1-040001.201505081133_all.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.1-wily/linux-headers-4.0.1-040001-generic_4.0.1-040001.201505081133_i386.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.1-wily/linux-image-4.0.1-040001-generic_4.0.1-040001.201505081133_i386.deb
```

for 64 bit :

```
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.1-wily/linux-headers-4.0.1-040001_4.0.1-040001.201505081133_all.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.1-wily/linux-headers-4.0.1-040001-generic_4.0.1-040001.201505081133_amd64.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.1-wily/linux-image-4.0.1-040001-generic_4.0.1-040001.201505081133_amd64.deb
```

after download , install them by

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.0.1*.deb linux-image-4.0.1*.deb
```

and restart by

```
sudo reboot
```

https://github.com/tavallaie/upgrade-kernel-4.0.1
* this script on github only work 64Bit os yet.